# Initialize qtip and immediately show on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am trying to initialize a qTip on the `click` event and display it at the mouse position at the same time (with the same click). I've got so far as to requiring 2 clicks in order to display it, but I would like to make it possible with only 1: http://jsfiddle.net/vpysbc5y/4/

Any brilliant ideas? Thanks.

```
<div id="block" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: black;"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#block').on('click', function() {
            $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'Hello, world!'
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'click',
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'unfocus',
                    fixed: true
                },
                position: {
                    at: 'top center',
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: {
                        mouse: false
                    }
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can't you use the qtip api to open it instead of using the click event? or use a custom event and trigger this after initializing it

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't open on the mouse position..

Comment: did you try adding `ready: true` to the `show` option?

Comment: yes @mic4ael, in that case it displays it, but not at the mouse position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `target: 'mouse'` (probably) tries to infer the current mouse position. However, outside a click event, this is not possible. Since your qtip will be shown on ready rather than on click then it can't infer the mouse position on its own so you will need to forward it.

Your code should read:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'Hello, world!'
                },
                show: {                    
                    ready : true
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'unfocus',
                    fixed: true
                },
                position: {
                    at: 'top center',
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    target: [ e.clientX, e.clientY ],
                    adjust: {
                        mouse: false
                    }
                },
         });
     });
});
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpysbc5y/6/)